# Variable initialization is delayed in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this code:

```
if "%2"=="32" (
set bit=This is 32bit
)
if "%2"=="64" (
set bit=This is 64bit
)
echo %bit%
)
```

When I tried using `sample.bat /s 64` the output is "This is 64bit", but when I tried using `sample.bat /s 32` the output is still "This is 64bit". Then I switch it back to sample.bat 64 the ouput became "This is 32bit". I think the variable initialization is being delayed. Does someone know a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `sample.bat 64`, the `64` is in `%1`, not `%2`. The first parameter passed to the batch file is always `%1` - the name of the batch file itself is in `%0`. You're getting some random output remnant or something left over from another attempt. Try this:

```
setlocal
if "%1"=="32" (
set bit=This is 32bit
)
if "%1"=="64" (
set bit=This is 64bit
)
echo %bit%
)
endlocal
```

`setlocal` makes sure that any environmental changes are discarded when your batch file ends, so you don't have to worry about getting leftovers from testing.

This still won't work properly if you just type `sample.bat`, because you haven't dealt with no parameters at all being passed.

Comment: +1 - Nice catch. I'm embarrassed to say that issue blew right past me without me picking up on it.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked.. Thanks! However, it should be evaluated in the second parameter. When I added "if first parameter is /s then go to second parameter and evaluate it if it's a 32 or 64 bit", the value seems stuck always at 32 bit. Can you please check my code in the answers below because I can't post it here in comments section..

Comment: It seems that I cannot post it in answers unless it's really an answer, I'll just put it here. 
NEW CODE:

    setlocal
    if "%1"=="/i" (
    if "%2"=="32" (
    set bit=This is 32bit
    ) 
    if "%2"=="64" (
    set bit=This is 64bit
    )
    echo %bit%
    endlocal
    )

The output is now stuck at "This is 32bit" regarding how many times I enter 64

Comment: I tried echoing the parameter inside the if statements. I've found out that the culprit is the parameter not being passed in the variable. Does setlocal have something to do with this?

Comment: I'm don't understand the problem. What does "parameter not being passed in the variable" mean? And if you want to test the effects of `setlocal`, just comment both that line and the `endlocal` one out (just place `::` at the beginning of each line).